# Dom4j get single node text value

Tags: java, dom4j

Assume I have

```
<Sports>
   <Soccer>  
      <Players>  
        <Player_1> Messi Leonel </Player_1>
      </Players>  
  </Soccer>  
</Sports>
```

How to get Player_1 node text in one line **without iteration** using Dom4J?
Return value should be: Messi Leonel
Thanks

Comment: I have this stuff: dom4j.Document, dom4j.Element, dom4j.SAXReader, dom4j.Element

Answer (score 3):

Got it, to the person who looks something like this

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file.xml");
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document  document = reader.read(file);
String name = document.selectSingleNode("//Sports/Soccer/Players/Player_1").getText();
```